# TYPO3 TCA and select form

Tags: typo3

I try to get values for my tca:

```
'config' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
    'items' => [
        ['Herr', 0],
        ['Frau', 1]
    ],
    'size' => 1,
    'maxitems' => 2,
    'eval' => 'required'
],
```

my form.html has this select types:

```
<label>Anrede</label>
<f:form.select name="salutation" class="form-control">
    <f:form.select.option value="0">Herr</f:form.select.option>
    <f:form.select.option value="1">Frau</f:form.select.option>
</f:form.select>
```

but i get always the first item: Herr, can somebody tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Since you are showing Fluid based HTML, what kind of form are we talking about?
TCA configures forms in the backend, while Fluid usually will be used in the frontend.

So IF your form is used to store user generated values in the frontend and send them to the database, maybe something else of the MVC chain is broken, but not the TCA.

So the next question is: Can you generate records with the list module in the backend and are their values stored properly?

Comment: Yes, i can generate both records in the backend, list and apply. After selecting a list item, i can choose it to show, and it is working so far. In the form every item will set in the db with the right value, only salutation is set with default value.

Comment: That does not answer the questions:
Is this form used in the frontend?
Are the records stored with a proper salutation value when creating them in the backend with the list module?

Comment: Yes, the form is used in the frontend. Yes, the records were stored with the right salutation value, if the value be created in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

For frontend forms with Extbase you will need a proper TypoScript conffiguration, a PHP newAction and/or createAction method and your Fluid template.

Based on the additional information now there are two options that came to my mind:

- Either the validation and storage of your form values is not
  configured properly, so they will be removed on the way to the
  database.
- Or you might have rendered the field twice with the same name in the
  frontend form, thus making the last entry the winner.

So please double check the fields first before digging deeper into the storage process.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/7-Controllers/1-Creating-Controllers-and-Actions.html

Comment: Thank you, Jo, I checked the two fields you mentioned, but it doesn't' t changed, but one thing I found, that makes me unsure if it's right or wrong, "salutation" is marked as string, should it not be an int value?

Comment: Where exactly is it marked as string and at whcih step in the process?
Is it just marked as string but still containing a proper "stringified" integer value, or is there already another string or just 0 in there?

Comment: It is marked in the model class JobApply as string, the value is empty string = default and the ext_tables.sql value is 'salutation int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL'.  I changed the fields in int, but still causing the same default value, always 0.